# AWS EC2 / Route 53 reverse DNS lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, elastic-ip

I have the following setup in EC2:

A server which has an Elastic IP assigned to it and a DNS name entry in Route 53 pointing to that Elastic IP.

Is it possible to retrieve the DNS name configured in Route 53 from the server that has the Elastic IP assigned? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [awscli](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) if you also know the hosted zone ID:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ZA6KYPP25HCIO | jq -j '.ResourceRecordSets[] | select (.Type=="A") | select (.ResourceRecords[].Value == "10.0.0.1") | (.Name|rtrimstr("."))'
```

where `ZA6KYPP25HCIO` is the hosted zone ID and 10.0.0.1 the IP of your host.

You can also [fill out a form](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) asking Amazon to create a DNS entry in the reverse zone pointing at your host.  If you do that, a simple `dig -x` or `nslookup` for the PTR record will give you the name.

AWS doesn't currently support automatic mapping of your Elastic IP addresses back to the DNS names you've created for them.

Comment: +1 Nice solution but needs `jq` error handling because every instance that **wasn't** 10.0.0.1 returns "cannot iterate over null". Just a `2>/dev/null` at the end of your line would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a reverse lookup with dig.

```
# dig -x 12.12.12.12
```

Obviously 12.12.12.12 is the IP you want to look up.

Are you trying to do this with the API instead? It looks like you should be able to do it with some magic. Take a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

Comment: the dig command returns the public DNS name of the instance (ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com) and not the Rout53 name. I already tested that before. I'll have a look at the API though!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Route53 name, but I assume you are talking about the A record? That'd be: ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx. It'd be easily parsed.